# How to disable default attribute in custom view(layout)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

Let's say I have a custom layout that extends from `ViewGroup`:

```
public class Square extends ViewGroup
```

To use my custom layout in .xml I need to do the following:

```
<com.blahblah.Square
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

Now I want to disable the possibility of using `layout_width` and `layout_height` for this layout in .xml file(because I'll use `sideOfSquare` attribute later).

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: in the constructor, remove (or modify) this attribute before passing it to `super()`. This won't prevent from using this attribute, but will make it be ignorred.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I want to disable this attributes "in .xml file".

Comment: you can't disable them since nobody limits you from using even non-existing attributes